# Openbib Class Option

Tags: bibliographies, class-options

I have been reading and reviewing class files as well as starting to read the Leslie Lamport's book on LaTeX. One thing I have noticed in multiple places (including the book) is an `openbib` option defined in the class file. But nowhere have I found described what it actually is (why is it an option?) or what it looks or why it is part of the [common format](https://tug.org/tugboat/tb28-1/tb88flynn.pdf) of class files. I don't think I have ever seen it actually used or specified in anyone else's documents before (in collaboration with colleagues I mean).

Is anyone familiar with it that could shed light on it or point me to a reference?

Comment: Just compare with and without the option the following example:  `\documentclass[openbib]{article}
\begin{document}
Sample\cite{Goossens97,Lamport94,Hanson93c}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{report}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

"Section 3.10: Open bibliography" of the [Standard Document Classes for LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/classes.pdf) says, "The option `openbib` produces the 'open' bibliography style, in which each block starts on a new line, and succeeding lines in a block are indented by `\bibindent`."